# Limited items in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have issue in my project is that:

-I have a listView with more than 1000 items. I dont want my listView load all 1000 items at once time. I just want to show 10 items on screen and have a "More" on bottom of my list. When I click "More", It will add more 10 items to my listView, and my listView will have 20 items. And it can be scrollable and "More" button is still there until my List have all 1000 items.

Does anyone have suggestion or code example?

Thanks in advance, any helps are appreciated.

Comment: see this example with Load More button http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/dynamic-custoized-list-view-in-android.html

Comment: This behaviour is alike with listView in Gmail native app.

Comment: @gtumca-MAC: I will have a try

Comment: @gtumca-MAC: It doesn't work. It loads all item...

Comment: please post your code here.....

Answer (score 3):

first of all - if the reason you don't want all 1000 items to be load ones is that you think that it makes the UI "heavy" because it contains 1000 views then you wrong.    list view have a mechanisem which taking care of holding in memory only the items that suppose to be visible.  it working the best when the implementation of the getView() method of the list adapter is re- using the convert view parameter properly.

if it's not the reason - then you can acheive it by implement the adapter to return at every module 10 position - a button that implements onClick listener which adding items to the logic data, and then calling notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh the UI properly to the new data

Comment: I know that listView reuse its UI, But each row in my list have some action: relating with database, reading file name from SDCard... I know it takes much time to prepare data.....

Comment: @tai.tran2008: if your data is coming from database - then the right thing to do is to extend CursorAdapter instead of BaseAdapter : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html   anyway: I assume your data structure contains String path to files you want to do something with,  so if this is the case - you should open the files for read and write on the getView() method also.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a webservice. try to create a stored procedure where you give the amount of items with it. each time you press the button more. the stored procedure will retrieve previous data + 10 more data items? it's maybe an option

Answer (score 0):

After an hour research, I resolve my problem is that:

-I implement `setOnScrollListener` to get lastIndex of my ListView

-Make a thread to update data to `adapter` using lastIndex with adding 10 items.

Here are description

```
 gtumcaDynamicListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        // what is the bottom iten that is visible
        int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
        if((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)) {
            //Run background thread
            Thread tt = new loadBackgroung(lastInScreen, adaptor);
            tt.start();
        }
    }
});


class loadBackgroung extends Thread{
public int lastIndex;
public MyCustomAdaptor adaptor;


public loadBackgroung(int lastIndex, MyCustomAdaptor adaptor) {
    super();
    this.lastIndex = lastIndex;
    this.adaptor = adaptor;
}

@Override
public void run() {


    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
                gtuMcaBean.add(new GtuMcaBean((lastIndex + i)+" First", (lastIndex + i)+" Last", (lastIndex + i)+" Birthdate"));
            }
            adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    loadingMore = false;

}
```

Complete code in : http://code.google.com/p/dynamic-listview/source/checkout